# web worker not communicating with react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-mediarecorder

I use [audio-recorder-polyfill](https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill) in my React project, to make possible audio recording for Safari. It seems to work in getting the recording to take place, however, no audio data gets available. The event "dataavailable" never gets fired, and no data seems to be "compiled" after stopping recording either.

```
   recordFunc() {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(stream => {
         recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
         // Set record to <audio> when recording will be finished
         recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', e => {
           this.audio.current.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
         })
         // Start recording
         recorder.start();
       })
   }
   stopFunc() {
      // Stop recording
      recorder.stop();
      // Remove “recording” icon from browser tab
      recorder.stream.getTracks().forEach(i => i.stop());
   }
```

Comment: Always check caniuse. In this case: https://caniuse.com/#search=dataavailable, so it's a pretty safe bet that this is entirely unsuported in Safari/webkit, and you're going to have to convince folks over on the webkit issue tracker that this should even be worked on

Comment: Supposedly the polyfill will add support for browsers that don't support it natively. But it would be good to know whether it does work at all in browsers that do support it or whether it's a problem of the polyfill.

Comment: The official demo of polyfill doesn't work properly in safari _(13.0.5)_ https://ai.github.io/audio-recorder-polyfill/

Comment: Have you tried assigning your handler as `recorder.ondataavailable = ( e => { ... } );` instead?

Comment: I have tried .ondataavailable, but still nothing @TheJim01 I tried this polyfill as bare as possible, locally, and it worked then. The issue arises when I incorporate the solution in my React project. I can't pinpoint what is not working though..

Comment: Can you add some more of your react code? Maybe a code sandbox link, problem might be somewhere else. Does it work out other browsers which support this natively?

Comment: If you say it worked locally (... by the way, what do you mean by locally?) but not in you React project, can you demonstrate the difference between successful and failed attempts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been a number of similar issues posted on [audio-recorder-polyfill's issue tracker](https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill/issues). 
[a](https://github.com/mmig/libflac.js/issues/6)
[b](https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill/issues/24)
[c](https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill/issues/32)
[d](https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill/issues/46)
[e](https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill/issues/47)

#### Root cause

One of those issues, [#4 (not listed above)](https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill/issues/4), is still open. Several comments on that issue tracker hint that the root issue is that Safari cancels the `AudioContext` if it was not created in a handler for a user interaction (e.g. a click).

#### Possible solutions

You may be able to get it to work if you:

1. Do the initialisation inside a handler for user interaction (i.e. `<button onclick="recordFunc()">`)
2. Do not attempt to reuse the `MediaStream` returned from `getUserMedia()` for multiple recordings
3. Do not attempt more than 4 (or 6?) audio recordings on the same page (sources [[1](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/pull/578)], [[2](https://old.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/7rlne0/audio_recording_in_safari/dsy8x9a/)] mention that Safari will block this)

#### Alternative libraries

You might also be able to try the [`StereoAudioRecorder` class](https://recordrtc.org/StereoAudioRecorder.html) from the [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC) package, which has more users (3K) but appears less maintained, and might work

#### Upcoming support

If you'd prefer to stick to the MediaRecorder API and the tips above don't work for you, the good news is that there is [experimental support for MediaRecorder in Safari 12.4 and up (iOS and macOS)](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mediarecorder), and it appears to be supported in the latest Safari Technology Preview.

#### See also

The [comments in this issue](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/issues/324) may also be useful

Comment: thank you very much, will look at your answer more thoroughly in a day or so.

Comment: @display-name-is-missing sounds good. Let me know if you have any questions or anything is unclear

Comment: As people say in the issues you linked to, different issues can be the cause for the problem. In my case, it was 1. Thank you for the help, mate!